# Практическая разница между Linq To Entites и Linq To Objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Изучая различия между LINQ To Entites и LINQ To Objects  в EntityFramework - столкнулся с интересной вещью :

```
var phones = db.Phones.Where(p=> p.CompanyId == 1).ToList().Where(p=> p.Id<10);
```

Здесь используются два метода `Where`, но их реализация будет различной. В первом случае, `db.Phones.Where(p=> p.CompanyId == 1)` транслируется в выражение SQL, которое было рассмотрено выше. Далее метод `ToList()` по результатам запроса создает список в памяти компьютера. После этого мы уже имеем дело со списком в памяти, а не с базой данных. И далее вызов Where`(p=> p.Id<10)` будет обращаться к списку в памяти и будет представлять Linq to Object.

И мне стало интересно : ***А не проще ли просто получать нужное значение из БД путем простого обращения через LINQ не используя при этом LINQ To Objects?***

Ведь запрос в даном случае будет выглядеть так :

```
var phones = db.Phones
.Where(p => p.CompanyId==1 &&
            p.TelephoneId<10)
```

*Хотелось бы узнать какой подход в данном случае будем эффективней и почему?*

Comment: ```LINQ To Entites и LINQ To Objects в EntityFramework ``` - Linq to Objects не часть EntityFramework. Естессвенно лучше все возможные фильтрации сделать запросом в БД и не гонять лишние данные. И в чем смысл селекта (```.Select(p=>new{...})```) в последней конструкции?

Comment: Представьте себе случай, когда таблица очень большая. Грузить всю таблицу в память и выкидывать ненужные объекты — не очень эффективный подход. Хуже того, вся таблица (или там нефильтрованный декартово произведение нескольких таблиц) в память может просто не влезть.

Comment: а вот так сразу нельзя спросить  у базы данных `db.Phones.Where(p=> p.CompanyId == 1 && p=> p.Id<10).ToList();` ?

Comment: @eikhner исправил

Comment: @tym32167 я знаю что `Entity To Objects` не является частью EF ,просто хотел узнать насколько неэффективно сначала добавлять в память ,а потом просто разгружать из нее большое количество данных (селект я уже поправил)

Comment: @VladD спасибо ,очень исчерпывающий ответ .Если несложно ,то не могли бы вы записать это как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите. Базы данных предназначены, кроме всего прочего, и для того, чтобы быстро и эффективно работать с большими объёмами данных. Например, базы данных легко справляются с выборкой из таблиц, больших по размеру, чем оперативная память. А вот получение целой такой таблицы в память с целью последующей фильтрации уже провалится по перерасходу памяти.

Также и фильтрация в базе данных может быть очень быстрой, т. к. если у неё есть индекс на фильтруемое поле, она может совместить фильтрацию с выборкой. (А особо умные базы данных могут, исходя из запросов, такой индекс и выстроить сами.) Если индекса нет, то всё равно польза от фильтрации на стороне базы в том, что выброшенные фильтром данные не нужно перегонять из базы в программу, и не нужно создавать их в основной программе только для того, чтобы тут же выбросить.

Поэтому обычно имеет смысл те части запроса, которые можно выполнить в базе данных (это та часть, при которой вы остаётесь в рамках `IQueryable`), выполнять на ней.

(Я не уверен, относится ли эта рекомендация к вложенным подзапросам, пускай лучше специалисты по базам данных поправят меня.)

К сожалению, скорость операций на базе данных имеет и обратную сторону: не все операции можно выполнить на базе данных, поэтому промежуточные результаты запроса приходится материализовать (то есть, получать из базы и загружать в память), используя `ToList` или `AsEnumerable`, и «дорабатывать напильником» в самой программе.

---

«Умения» различных баз данных отличаются между собой. Обычно база данных должна уметь фильтровать не только по равенству поля значению, но и уметь сравнивать с константой. Судя по всему, либо вам попался код для менее продвинутой базы данных (да, абстракции протекают), либо автор кода ошибся. Либо это «костыль» под какой-нибудь баг. Если сравнение возможно выполнить на базе данных, его стоит именно там и выполнять.

Comment: Вот, кстати, интересно, запрос в том виде, в котором привел его автор. Он ведь получается загрузит из базы все `Phones` у которых `CompanyId == 1` и _закеширует их_ в Local (или как это там в EF называется), затем из них выберет только часть, а остальные останутся закешированными. И если дальше нам потребуются другие `Phones` с `CompanyId == 1`, то они будут получены без повторного запроса в БД. Это может иметь смысл, если я не ошибся в своих рассуждениях...

Comment: @Андрей: Может быть, это было логикой запроса, да. Если данных с CompanyId == 1 мало, то конечно лучше загрузить из в память. Тут уже лучше просто спрофилировать. С другой стороны, если данных _мало_, то можно их загрузить в память и полностью, разменяв транзакции на скорость.

Comment: @Андрей да, а еще, в зависимости от структуры данных и индексов, выполнить второй запрос Where может быть дешевле в памяти на объектах, чем напрямую в базе. На примере Where это не так очевидно, но вот Sort достаточно часто работает в C# быстрее, чем в SQL. Просто такими оптимизациями нельзя заниматься без предварительных замеров.

Comment: @PashaPash: Вы бы написали свой ответ, а? Я помню, вы много работали с базами данных.

Comment: @PashaPash, а вот еще интересно, ведь бывают, например, вычисляемые свойства, которые в БД не хранятся и нам нужно по этому свойству фильтровать, тогда потребуется материализация запроса? (странно было бы, конечно, если бы такое поле называлось Id)

Answer (score 3):

В общем случае, вы конечно правы, проще получить одним запросом к БД, чем фильтровать потом в оперативной памяти. Но тут есть несколько нюансов.

Во-первых мы должны учитывать, что в базе данных таблица несколько более сложна чем мы можем видеть в нашем коде, с ней связаны еще такие сущности как и индексы, триггеры и тд... Поэтому добавление какого либо дополнительного условия, может порождать "плохой" план запроса с полным перебором довольно больших объемов данных (например если `Id` входит только в составной индекс, да, для поля с таким названием это было бы странно, но... ). В таком случае, иногда, проще выбрать только небольшую часть данных, материализовать их (`ToList()`), и отфильтровать их уже в памяти, вместо проведения рефакторинга всей БД.

Во-вторых `Phones` может быть не таблицей, а представлением, и планы запросов станут в таком случае еще сложнее.